# How to understand which property is suitable for NSDictionary eg. retain or assign?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, properties, nsdictionary

now i using

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *currentAttribute;
```

if i use copy or assign instead of retain is it more difference in memory performance?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Declaring it `copy` would mean you get an entirely new `NSDictionary` object for use with your class. If it's quite a large dictionary this can be a performance hit; not very noticeable, but significant anyway. By `retain`ing it, you simply give your class its own pointer to the same `NSDictionary` instance.

Declaring it `assign` puts your application at risk of crashing in case the `NSDictionary` is autoreleased. If it ends up in the pool and gets deallocated because the pool reduced its retain count to 0, your class won't get to access it anymore, causing a crash.

Comment: `retain` is also called `strong`. If somebody is wandering what is `strong`.